# How do i combine 3 columns and get the frequency of them?

Tags: r, frequency

I currently have this table given to me:

```
   City_Category               Cat1               Cat2               Cat3
1               A                  3                  0                  0
2               A                  1                  6                 14
3               C                  4                  5                  9
4               A                 12                 14                  0
5               C                  8                  0                  0
6               A                  1                  2                  0
7               A                 12                 14                 17
```

The numbers under the category 1,2 and 3 are sort of the categories where the products fall under. How do I combine them together to make a table like the following?

```
    City_Category               Category               Freq
1               A                      0                  4
2               B                      0                  0
3               C                      0                  2
...
17              A                      14                 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(df, name, Category, -City_Category) %>%
  count(City_Category, Category, name = 'Freq')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
   City_Category Category  Freq
   <fct>            <int> <int>
 1 A                    0     4
 2 A                    1     2
 3 A                    2     1
 4 A                    3     1
 5 A                    6     1
 6 A                   12     2
 7 A                   14     3
 8 A                   17     1
 9 C                    0     2
10 C                    4     1
11 C                    5     1
12 C                    8     1
13 C                    9     1
```

Data used:

```
df <- structure(list(City_Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "C"), class = "factor"), Cat1 = c(3L, 
1L, 4L, 12L, 8L, 1L, 12L), Cat2 = c(0L, 6L, 5L, 14L, 0L, 2L, 
14L), Cat3 = c(0L, 14L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

---

If for some reason you cannot work with the latest `dplyr` version, you can do:

```
gather(df, name, Category, -City_Category) %>%
  count(City_Category, Category) %>%
  rename(Freq = n)
```

Comment: Error in count(., City_Category, Category, name = "Freq") : 
  unused argument (name = "Freq")

Comment: Install the latest `dplyr` version by `install.packages('dplyr')`. Otherwise see my edit.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer if it helped.